# Vue3 used socket.io-client 3.0: Cannot read property 'sid' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, websocket, socket.io, vuejs3

Socket.IO version 3.0.3 can't connect with Socket.IO server.
My code in Vue:

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client'

export default {
  install: (app, { connection, options }) => {
    const socket = io(connection, options)
    app.config.globalProperties.$socket = socket
    app.provide('socket', socket)
  }
}
```

In file main.js

```
import Socketio from '@/plugins/Socket';
app.use(Socketio, {
  connection: 'http://127.0.0.1:3001',
  options: {
    debug: true,
    transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
  },
});
```

And it throw error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sid' of undefined
    at Socket.onpacket (socket.js?7851:189)
    at Manager.eval (index.js?40de:21)
    at Manager.Emitter.emit (index.js?7297:145)
    at Manager.ondecoded (manager.js?3d54:209)
    at Decoder.eval (index.js?40de:21)
    at Decoder.Emitter.emit (index.js?7297:145)
    at Decoder.add (index.js?8205:117)
    at Manager.ondata (manager.js?3d54:201)
    at Socket.eval (index.js?40de:21)
    at Socket.Emitter.emit (index.js?7297:145)
```

How can I fix it?